# Python openpyxl apply number format on 2 different column ranges

Tags: python, openpyxl

I'm trying to figure out how to apply formatting to 2 different columns without doing 2 separate loops.

```
#Current Version:
from openpyxl import load_workbook
from openpyxl.utils.dataframe import dataframe_to_rows
from openpyxl.styles import *
from openpyxl.descriptors import (
    String,
    Sequence,
    Integer,
)
from openpyxl.descriptors.serialisable import Serialisable


BUILTIN_FORMATS = {   
    5: '"$"#,##0_);("$"#,##0)',
    }

frmt = BUILTIN_FORMATS[5]

for row in ws["D2:"+"D"+str(rows)]:
    for cell in row:
        cell.number_format = frmt

for row in ws["G2:"+"G"+str(rows)]:
    for cell in row:
        cell.number_format = frmt
```

What would allow me to do something like?

```
for row in ws["D2:"+"D"+str(rows)+','+"G2:"+"G"+str(rows)]:
    for cell in row:
        cell.number_format = frmt
```

I was thinking something with openpyxl.worksheet.cell_range.MultiCellRange  but I couldn't figure out how to get it working.

Answer (score 2):

```
for row in ws["D:G"]:
    cells = row[0], row[-1]
    for c in cells:
        c.number_format = frmt
```

If you want to start on row 2, you're best off using `ws.iter_rows()`